# Uncaught Exception java.lang.IllegalAccessError:

Tags: java

Folks
I'm trying to perform Performance Testing but unable to save, save as, open etc. operations and it logs the errors in the command prompt or you may see the errors highlighted in the snip. Please help me with its solution. Thanking you in anticipation. [Please click this link to find attached snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62x4H.png)

Comment: Post code, error messages etc as text and not as images

Answer (score 0):

The Java version being used on a computer was an outdated one, Upon updating the Java version, it worked.